# Issue Copying file via FOR /r Command

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Just want to thank anyone for helping me out with this issue. its kind of a pain in my rear.

Anyways, what I am trying to do is copy a single file to every sub directory of any specified sub- directory. The issue I am having, is that it is just not actually copying.....

I think this may be because there is some sort of error with the path. I have narrowed it down to that being the culprite. Something about spaces in the path.

With this program, I ask the user for the directory in which they want to copy the file to all the specified directories sub-directories. Then I ask for which file they want to copy, and then boom. I run a FOR /R to execute the copy over and over. However, when I do this with a path that has a space in it Example:Program Files, the file does not copy.

I have tried various things such as quoting, setting program files to Progra~1, but I just cannot figure it out. can you guys help please?

```
ECHO OFF
REM Batch file for copying and pasting user specified file into every sub-folder
REM of a specified folder.
ECHO NOTE! Make sure before you run this program, that you have
ECHO completed the following.
ECHO .
ECHO 1. Your file that you wish to be copied is in the same
ECHO directory as this batch file.
echo .
ECHO 2. When specifying the file to be copied, only include
ECHO the file name and extension. example: Test.txt
echo .

set /p Directory=Enter the folder path where the file will be copied:%=%

set /p FileToCopy=Enter the File name and extension:%=%

FOR /R %~Directory% %%G IN (%FileToCopy%) DO copy %FileToCopy% %%G
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the FOR a bit backwards.

Try starting with something like this instead:

```
@echo off
set /p BaseTargetFolder=Full Path to Base Target Folder: 
set /p File=Full Path to File: 
cd %BaseTargetFolder%
copy "%File%" "%BaseTargetFolder%"
for /d /r %%G in ("*") do copy "%File%" "%%G"
pause
```

Here is the result.

```
Full Path to Base Target Folder: C:\My Test
Full Path to File: C:\Temp\Test.txt
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is the folder structure I used to test:

```
"C:\My Test\Test 1"
"C:\My Test\Test 2"
"C:\My Test\Test 1\Test 1A"
"C:\My Test\Test 1\Test 1B"
"C:\My Test\Test 1\Test 1A\Test 1A1"
"C:\My Test\Test 1\Test 1A\Test 1A2"
"C:\My Test\Test 1\Test 1B\Test 1B1"
"C:\My Test\Test 1\Test 1B\Test 2B1"
"C:\My Test\Test 2\Test 2A"
"C:\My Test\Test 2\Test 2B"
"C:\My Test\Test 2\Test 2A\Test 2A1"
"C:\My Test\Test 2\Test 2A\Test 2A2"
"C:\My Test\Test 2\Test 2B\Test 2B1"
"C:\My Test\Test 2\Test 2B\Test 2B2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it almost done

```
set /p "Directory=Enter the folder path where the file will be copied: "
set /p "FileToCopy=Enter the File name and extension: "

FOR /D /R "%Directory%" %%G IN (*) DO copy "%FileToCopy%" "%%~fG"
```

What you need to iterate is the folder structure, not the file to copy, and the quotes will handle the space problem in paths.

If the file needs to be copied also to the indicated folder, replace `*` with `.` so the starting folder will be also included.